# Connecting Vagrant VM to LAN

Tags: virtual-machine, ubuntu-14.04, virtualbox, homestead

I am running Vagrant and VirtualBox on Ubuntu 14.04. My web app is built with Laravel and uses Homestead.

The application makes a web service call to a machine on my local area network. I can successfully reach the server from my OS web browser.

However, my web application cannot access this web service as it does not appear to be sharing my local network settings.

Based on my Google searches I have tried changing the Network settings in VirtualBox under the "Attached To" setting. Changing Adapter 1 to Bridged Adapter. However, this did not work.

Is there a way to allow my VM to communicate with a web service on my LAN?

Comment: it's probably your switch not allowing it (more than two cards on the same port) - I cannot remember how it's called but it's really no programming question at all

Comment: Your VM could be set up for NAT as well, so it'll look to the VM like it's not sharing the local network settings, but when the traffic exist VirtualBox, it actually is.  When the adapter is set to bridged, it'll need to get an IP address from your DHCP server (is it?)  Can you get to the web service using the browser in your VM?  (And Carsten is right, this is not a programming question.)

Answer (score 0):

**aaronfarr**, 
I have as host Win7_64 with VirtualBox and as VM an openSuse.

With network configured like in the below picture and also inside VM the same proxy settings like on host, I can do same things both on VM and host machine.

[image]